# Make counter cache column read only in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

What is the best way of making the column readonly, so that we cannot write the value to that column, even while creating the record. I know there is `:attr_readonly` provided, but this does not prevents writing to the column while creating the record.

Comment: why would you want to do that? just don't write to it.

Comment: @Pascal exactly - this problem is solved by using strong attributes to control the inputs into the model. The counter cache can't actually work if you made it read only as Rails would not be able to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Rails version are you talking about, but the `counter_cache` option adds the column to the model's list of read-only attributes.

Excerpt from [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

> Counter cache columns are added to the containing model's list of read-only attributes through attr_readonly.

If this does not prevent writing to the column during creation, you can add a callback like this (assuming your column is called `books_count`):

```
before_save :reset_books_count, if: :will_save_change_to_books_count?

def reset_books_count
  self.books_count = self.books_count_was
end
```

This callback will get skipped when `counter_cache` uses it since it uses `increment!` internally which skips callbacks.